# Проблемы при работе с функцией fabs

Tags: c

Когда я вызываю функцию fabs для аргумента z типа double (в тот момент равного -10.47749), я внезапно получаю на выход значение типа int равное 4991. В чём проблема, и как правильно взять модуль от числа?

```
double segment_area(double d, double friend_r, double foe_r)
{
    double z = (foe_r * foe_r) - (friend_r * friend_r);
    double alpha = 2.0 * asin(friend_r - ((((d - (fabs(z) / d)) / 2.0) * ((d - (fabs(z) / d)) / 2.0))) / friend_r);
    printf("%lf\n", alpha);
    return 0;
}
```

Дебаг-версия функции, которая по заданному расстоянию центров окружностей и их радиусам считает радианную меру центрального угла, образованного точками пересечения этих окружностей

Comment: Дайте проблемный кусочек кода и его контекст.

Comment: Добавил, но, как мне кажется, это только отвлечёт внимание от проблемы - ибо проблема возникает после вызова функции; входные данные корректны

Comment: @АлександрЧи пожалуйста, добавьте [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Например, [тут](http://ideone.com/dTkT3J) я вызвал вашу функцию и fabs с какими-то параметрами и получил какой-то ответ, но абсолютно непонятно, есть ли проблема.

Comment: Вполне вероятно, что проблема на самом деле у вас в другом месте программы, а тут вы всего лишь получаете последствия.

Comment: Хм, а при выполнении программы при выделении выражения fabs(z) отладчик будет ведь не результат выполнения показывать, да?
IDE Code::Blocks с MinGW, GDB/CDB отладчик

Answer (score 1):

Исправляйте все ваши константы на double:

```
double segment_area(double d, double friend_r, double foe_r)
{
    double z = (foe_r * foe_r) - (friend_r * friend_r);
    double alpha = 2.0 * asin(friend_r - ((((d - (fabs(z) / d)) / 2.0) * ((d - (fabs(z) / d)) / 2.0))) / friend_r);
    printf("%lf\n", alpha);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: К сожалению, не помогло(

Во время выполнения программы я отладчиком проверяю возвращаемое значение fabs(z), и он показывает: int 4991

Но, на всякий случай, исправлю и константы =D

Answer (score 0):

Как ни странно, помогло преобразование кода:

```
double segment_area(double d, double friend_r, double foe_r)
{
    double z = (foe_r * foe_r) - (friend_r * friend_r);
    z = fabs(z);
    double alpha = 2.0 * asin(friend_r - ((((d - (z / d)) / 2.0) * ((d - (z / d)) / 2.0))) / friend_r);
    printf("%lf\n", alpha);
    return 0;
```

}

Однако, я всё равно не понимаю, в чём причина такого поведения функции